# DiscordJS move all members in a specific vc

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, discord.js

I'm trying to find a way to move all members which are in a specific vc to the vc which the sender of the command is in. The command should be -warp. This is what i have so far:

```
        if (!message.member?.permissions.has('MOVE_MEMBERS')) return;
        const member = message.mentions.members?.first();
        if (!member) return message.reply("Error: Didn't specify member.");
        if (!member.voice.channel) return message.reply("Error: Mentioned member is not in a Voice Channel.");

        if (!message.member.voice.channel) return message.reply("Error: Executor of command is not in a Voice Channel.");
        member.voice.setChannel(message.member.voice.channel)
        message.reply('Success: Moved member.')
```

It works but i can only move one user at the time and from every vc. I want everyone to be able to move others but only from a specific vc.
Thanks for your help!

Comment: Is your file type TypeScript or JavaScript

Comment: Typescript. Sorry for not specifying that.

Comment: You did but you selected both typescript and javascript for your question tags.

Answer (score 1):

Give this a try

```js
    const channel2pullFrom = message.guild.channels.cache.get(‘channelID’)
    const sendersChannel = message.member.voice.channel.id

    if (!message.member.permissions.has('MOVE_MEMBERS')) return
    if (!message.member.voice.channel) return message.reply("Error: Executor of command is not in a Voice Channel.")
   
    channel2pullFrom.members.map((member) => {
        member.voice.setChannel(sendersChannel)
    })
   
    message.reply(`Moved members.`)
```

Code:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/JLrmP.png

Before Command:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/VGbyp.png

After Command:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/tTUF4.png

Comment: Using that code i get the error `Property 'size' does not exist on type 'Collection<string, GuildMember>` and `Property 'forEach' does not exist on type 'Collection<string, GuildMember>`.  error: **TS2339**.

Comment: Weird cause it works on my bot updating my answer with images

Comment: @NoBypass try it now and see if it works

Answer (score 0):

This works for me, let me know if you have any troubles:

```
client.on('messageCreate', async message => {
    if (message.author.bot) return;
    if (message.content === '-warp') {
        // doing the same validation here as you did
        if (!message.member.voice.channel) {
            await message.reply('Error: Executor of command is not in a Voice Channel.');
            return;
        }
        const sendersChannel = message.member.voice.channel;
        const mentionedMember = message.mentions.members?.first();
        if (!mentionedMember) {
            await message.reply('Error: Didn\'t specify member.');
            return;
        }
        if (!mentionedMember.voice.channel) {
            await message.reply('Error: Mentioned member is not in a Voice Channel.');
            return;
        }
        // get the channel of the mentioned member
        const targetChannel = mentionedMember.voice.channel;
        // iterate over all the members in that voice channel and move them to the sender's channel
        for (const [, member] of targetChannel.members) {
            await member.voice.setChannel(sendersChannel);
        }
        await message.reply(`Moved all members from ${targetChannel.name} to ${sendersChannel.name}`);
    }
});
```

Comment: This would work but im trying to make it so it always takes the users from the same channel. The idea is that when you type "-warp" it doesnt a need specification of a user and moves everyone from a vc to the vc the executor is in. The vc where the users should get pulled from is always the same one. Sry for not explaining my problem well enough.