# TS2339 Error: "Property 'forEach' does not exist on type 'Collection<string, GuildMember>" DiscordJS

Tags: typescript, discord.js

When trying to use the following code i get the error messages `Property 'forEach' does not exist on type 'Collection<string, GuildMember>` and `Property 'size' does not exist on type 'Collection<string, GuildMember>`

```
import { Message } from "discord.js";

export default {
    callback: async (message: Message, ...args: string[]) => {
        const channel2pullFrom = message.guild.channels.cache.get('964675235314020442')
        const sendersChannel = message.member.voice.channel.id
        const totalCount = channel2pullFrom.members.size
    
        if (!message.member.permissions.has('MOVE_MEMBERS')) return
        if (!message.member.voice.channel) return message.reply("Error: Executor of command is not in a Voice Channel.")
       
        channel2pullFrom.members.forEach((member) => {
            member.voice.setChannel(sendersChannel)
        })
       
        message.reply(`Moved ${totalCount} members.`)
    }
}
```

I have no idea why that's happening and couldn't find anything abour this error when working with DiscordJS.

Here's the full error log:

```
    return new TSError(diagnosticText, diagnosticCodes);
           ^
TSError: ⨯ Unable to compile TypeScript:
commands/warp.ts:7:53 - error TS2339: Property 'size' does not exist on type 'Collection<string, GuildMember> | ThreadMemberManager'.
  Property 'size' does not exist on type 'ThreadMemberManager'.

7         const totalCount = channel2pullFrom.members.size
                                                      ~~~~
commands/warp.ts:12:34 - error TS2339: Property 'forEach' does not exist on type 'Collection<string, GuildMember> | ThreadMemberManager'.
  Property 'forEach' does not exist on type 'ThreadMemberManager'.

12         channel2pullFrom.members.forEach((member) => {
                                    ~~~~~~~
```

When console logging 'message.member.voice' this get's logged:

```
VoiceState {
  guild: <ref *1> Guild {
    id: '897642715368534027',
    name: 'Free Depression Store',
    icon: '55bbdc9124e504f062e5377a2fc4066e',
    features: [ 'COMMUNITY', 'NEWS' ],
    commands: GuildApplicationCommandManager {
      permissions: [ApplicationCommandPermissionsManager],
      guild: [Circular *1]
    },
    members: GuildMemberManager { guild: [Circular *1] },
    channels: GuildChannelManager { guild: [Circular *1] },
    bans: GuildBanManager { guild: [Circular *1] },
    roles: RoleManager { guild: [Circular *1] },
    presences: PresenceManager {},
    voiceStates: VoiceStateManager { guild: [Circular *1] },
    stageInstances: StageInstanceManager { guild: [Circular *1] },
    invites: GuildInviteManager { guild: [Circular *1] },
    scheduledEvents: GuildScheduledEventManager { guild: [Circular *1] },
    available: true,
    shardId: 0,
    splash: null,
    banner: null,
    description: null,
    verificationLevel: 'LOW',
    vanityURLCode: null,
    nsfwLevel: 'DEFAULT',
    discoverySplash: null,
    memberCount: 55,
    large: true,
    premiumProgressBarEnabled: false,
    applicationId: null,
    afkTimeout: 300,
    afkChannelId: null,
    systemChannelId: null,
    premiumTier: 'NONE',
    premiumSubscriptionCount: 0,
    explicitContentFilter: 'ALL_MEMBERS',
    mfaLevel: 'NONE',
    joinedTimestamp: 1648975385274,
    defaultMessageNotifications: 'ONLY_MENTIONS',
    systemChannelFlags: SystemChannelFlags { bitfield: 0 },
    maximumMembers: 500000,
    maximumPresences: null,
    approximateMemberCount: null,
    approximatePresenceCount: null,
    vanityURLUses: null,
    rulesChannelId: '964671035213488128',
    publicUpdatesChannelId: '954169682619957318',
    preferredLocale: 'en-US',
    ownerId: '672835870080106509',
    emojis: GuildEmojiManager { guild: [Circular *1] },
    stickers: GuildStickerManager { guild: [Circular *1] }
  },
  id: '672835870080106509',
  serverDeaf: null,
  serverMute: null,
  selfDeaf: null,
  selfMute: null,
  selfVideo: null,
  sessionId: null,
  streaming: null,
  channelId: null,
  requestToSpeakTimestamp: null
}
C:\Users\nobyp\OneDrive\Dokumente\.main\code\bypassbot\commands\warp.ts:4
    callback: async (message: Message, ...args: string[]) => {
           ^
TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'id')
```

Comment: Might want to do a check if `channel2pullFrom ` exists.

Comment: The full error code would have helped in your original question here. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71892102/discordjs-move-all-members-in-a-specific-vc/71892371#71892371

Comment: Your question looks for a way to move members from one vc to another but your error shows the channel you are trying to pull from us a thread not a vc

Comment: Your error relates to a threadMemberManager https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/ThreadMemberManager rather than a voiceChannel https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/VoiceChannel through which members are an element of

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will check that the channel being pulled from is a voice channel and `return` if it isn’t. If you run this and nothing happens and nothing errors then the channel if you set for `channel2pullFrom` is not a VC

The issue was that the correct intents were not specified. Change intents to `intents: 32767,`

```js
import { Message } from "discord.js";

export default {
    callback: async (message: Message, ...args: string[]) => {
        const channel2pullFrom = message.guild.channels.cache.get('964675235314020442')
    // you could also dynamically set this by making it one of the args
    // const channel2pullFrom = message.guild.channels.cache.get(args[0])
    // above line won’t work without knowing more on how your args are handled (are they shifted, etc)
        if (channel2pullFrom.type != 'GUILD_VOICE') {
            return
        } else {
            const sendersChannel = message.member.voice.channelId
            const totalCount = channel2pullFrom.members.size
    
            if (!message.member.permissions.has('MOVE_MEMBERS')) return
            if (!message.member.voice.channel) return message.reply("Error: Executor of command is not in a Voice Channel.")
       
            channel2pullFrom.members.forEach((member) => {
            member.voice.setChannel(sendersChannel)
            })
       
            message.reply(`Moved ${totalCount} members.`)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Using that I still get an error: 
`callback: async (message: Message, ...args: string[]) => {
           ^
TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'id')` I always get that error, no matter if I'm in a vc or not.
I tried moving the line with `const sendersChannel = message.member.voice.channel.id` below the error line but then the error just always triggers. We're getting there tho...

Comment: `console.log(message.member.voice)` put that right under the else line. Then post the results in your question above

Comment: And you were in a voice channel when you ran that right? If so, on you main bot page change your intents to say `intents: 32767,` instead of defining them individually

Comment: This works! I had to put the line with error right below the "else" tho since it otherwise wouldn't trigger at all. With this change it works tho. You might want to change that in your answer.

Comment: UPDATE intents: 32767 no longer includes all intents, all intents is now 131071, just fyi since I can't update a comment